# jspdf/html2canvas cutting off data

Tags: php, jspdf, html2canvas

I have taken a look at other related questions but unable to understand or change this to get it working.  Basically i am trying to save a pdf of presented flot data contained in tab0 .  for some reason the pdf output cuts half the page off, even though I am using the largest size a0 and it is also missing the legend of charts, here is the code.

```
(function ($) {
  $(function() {
//    $.plot($("#placeholder0"), [ { label: 'Test', data: [[0, 0], [1, 1]] } ], { yaxis: { max: 1 } });

    $("#generate0").on("click", function(e) {

      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a0');
  //    var pdf = new jsPDF();
      var canvas = pdf.canvas;

      canvas.height = 6000;

      html2canvas($('#content').get(0), {
          canvas:canvas,
          allowTaint: true,
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
      //      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            console.log("rendered");
          /*    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
              iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:10000px; width:500px');
              document.body.appendChild(iframe);
              iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring'); */

              pdf.save("Current Data2.pdf")
             //var div = document.createElement('pre');
             //div.innerText=pdf.output();
             //document.body.appendChild(div);
          }
      });

    });
});
}(jQuery))
```

all i want to do is allow the saved pdf to capture all of the data even if it means spanning over 3 or 10 pdf pages.  Any help greatly recieved... oh here is the html/php ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- start: Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vibe Music Therapy Dashboard</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Vibe Music Therapy Daashboard - OpenFace Service user 1 Data">
  <meta name="author" content="Greg Hanford">
  <meta name="keyword" content="Vibe, MusicTherapy, Dashboard, Metrics, disability, support, research, kpi">
  <!-- end: Meta -->

  <!-- start: Mobile Specific -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- end: Mobile Specific -->

  <!-- start: CSS -->
   <!-- <link id="bootstrap-style" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link id="base-style" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link id="base-style-responsive" href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/graphing.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/91366f1215.js"></script>

  <!-- end: CSS -->


  <!-- The HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <link id="ie-style" href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

  <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link id="ie9style" href="css/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

  <!-- start: Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
  <!-- end: Favicon -->

  <!-- Piwik -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
      "https://sweb5.secure-secure.co.uk/musictherapy.co.uk/piwik/" :
      "http://musictherapy.co.uk/piwik/");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    try {
      var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 1);
      piwikTracker.trackPageView();
      piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
    } catch (err) {}
  </script><noscript><p><img src="http://musictherapy.co.uk/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
  <!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->


</head>

<body>
  <!-- start: Header -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner"><img class="main-logo" style="width: 150px; height: 74px;" alt="vibe dashboard logo" src="img/Vibe-dashboard-logo.png">
      <a class="brand" href="index.html"><span>Music Therapy Dashboard</span></a>
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".top-nav.nav-collapse,.sidebar-nav.nav-collapse">


      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- start: Header -->

  <div class="container-fluid-full">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <!-- start: Main Menu -->
      <div id="sidebar-left" class="span2">
        <div class="nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
            <li>
              <a class="dropmenu" href="#"><i class="icon-folder-close-alt"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Davenham Metrics</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="overview-main1.html"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Overview</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser1.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Joyce</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser2.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Margaret</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser3.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Jenny</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser4.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Gillian</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser5.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Alf</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser6.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Jean</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser7.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Maureen</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser8.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Judith</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu" href="musictherapy-serviceuser9.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Wendy</span></a></li>

              </ul>
            </li><li>
              <a class="dropmenu" href="#"><i class="icon-folder-close-alt"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> OpenFace Data</span></a>
              <ul>
                <?php
                                $data = "./data";
                                $dir = scandir($data);

                                $users = [];

                                // $i starts at 2 to skip the dir entries '.' and '..'

                                for ($i = 2, $size = count($dir); $i < $size; ++$i) {
                                    $users[] = explode("-", $dir[$i])[0];
                                }

                                foreach (array_unique($users) as $user){
                                    echo '<li> <a class="submenu2" href="graph.php?user=' . $user . '">',
                                    '<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet">' . $user . '</span></a></li>';
                                }
                                 ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end: Main Menu -->

      <noscript>
                <div class="alert alert-block span10">
                    <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
                    <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a> enabled to use this site.</p>
                </div>
            </noscript>

      <!-- start: Content -->



      <div id="content" class="span10">
        <?php
        $user = $_GET['user'];

        $data_dir = "./data";
        $dir_listing = scandir($data_dir);
        $users = [];

        // $i starts at 2 to skip the dir entries '.' and '..'

        for ($i = 2, $size = count($dir_listing); $i < $size; ++$i) {
          $split = explode("-", $dir_listing[$i]);

          $users[$split[0]][] = $split[1];
        }

        $dates = array_unique($users[$user]);
        $overview = array_search('Overview', $dates);
        if($overview) {
          unset($dates[$overview]);
          array_unshift($dates,'Overview');
        }
        $dates = array_values($dates);

      //  print_r("DATES");
    //    print_r($dates);
         ?>
        <div class="box-content">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">



<?php
  echo '<li class="active"><a href="#tab0">' . $dates[0] . '</a></li>';
  for($i = 1, $size = count($dates); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    echo '<li><a href="#tab' . $i . '">' . $dates[$i] . ' </a></li>';
  }
 ?>


          </ul>


        </div>

        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

          <?php
            foreach ($dates as $id => $date) {
                if ($id == 0) {
                  echo '<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab0">';
                } else {
                  echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' . $id . '">';
                }
                echo <<<END
                <div class="row-fluid">
                  <button type="button" disabled class="select-chart btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#main-variable$id">
                  Loading chart data</button>
                  <button type="button" disabled class="select-features btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                  Loading features data</button>
                  <button type="button" id="generate$id">Generate pdf</button>
                  <div id="triple-chart-holder$id" class="container charts"></div>
                  <div id="single-chart-holder$id" class="container charts"></div>
                  <div id="features-chart-holder$id" class="container charts"></div>
                  <div id="features$id" class="f-chart", style="height:382px"></div>
                  <div id="features-translation$id" class="f-chart", style="height:282px"></div>
                  <div id="features-rotation$id" class="f-chart", style="height:282px"></div>
                  <div class="container charts">
                    <div id="radar$id" style="width:1000px; height:1000px"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="dial-chart-holder$id" class="container charts"></div>
                  <div id="placeholder$id" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
                </div>


                      <!-- Modal -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="comparison$id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="choose comparisions modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Select datasets for comparison</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div id="IMT$id" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                  IMT
                                </div>
                                <div id="OOT$id" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                   OOT
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              <button type="button" class="plot-chart btn btn-primary">Plot</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Modal -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="main-variable$id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="main variable modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select independent dataset</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div id="IMT-main$id" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                IMT
                              </div>
                              <div id="OOT-main$id" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                OOT
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              <button type="button" class="select-all-imt btn btn-secondary">Select all, IMT</button>
                              <button type="button" class="select-all-oot btn btn-secondary">Select all, OOT</button>
                              <button type="button" class="main-variable btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                        </div>




END;
            }
           ?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <footer>

    <p>
      <span style="text-align:left;float:left">&copy; 2016 <a href="http://www.musictherapy.co.uk" alt="Vibe Music Therapy Dashboard">Vibe Music Therapy Dashboard</a></span>

    </p>

  </footer>

  <!-- start: JavaScript-->

  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="js/excanvas.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>

  <script src="js/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/counter.js"></script>
  <script src="js/retina.js"></script>
  <script src="js/papaparse.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.viewport.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.downsample.js"></script>

  <script src="js/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.JUMlib.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.spider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flot.grow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/async.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prepareplots.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  (function () {
    // defensively json_encode(ing) to make sure nothing odd gets passed to the
    // javascript.
    var dirRoot = <?php echo json_encode($data_dir . "/" . $user . "-") ?>;
    var dates = <?php echo json_encode($dates) ?>;
    $(function () {
      preparePlots(0, dirRoot + dates[0]);
    });

    $('.nav-pills a').on('click', function() {
      var id = $(this).parent('li').index();
      preparePlots(id, dirRoot + dates[id]);
    });

  })();

  </script>
  <!-- end: JavaScript-->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue, I found that it's not the problem of jsPDF page size, but the html2canvas.

If you indicate canvas option to html2canvas, then html2canvas won't probably capture the element `$('#content').get(0)` by its width, it will capture this element by the width of whole window, if the width of the canvas is less than the window's, the captured picture cutting off.

have a try :

`canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth`

It's not a final solution, but works for me.